# javascriptserializer throws circular reference when serializing model object in customer resolver of automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

Here is the class in which i am trying to bind my serialized object.

```
 public class RequestModel<T>:Event
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public T Model{ get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        public string EntityType => typeof(T).ToString();

        //public string EntityType => typeof(T).ToString();
        public UserDataViewModel UserData { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
        public override Type RequestEntityType { get { return typeof(T); }}
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public RequestModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }


    }

public class RequestModelMapper : Profile
    {
        public RequestModelMapper()
        {

            CreateMap(typeof(RequestModel<>), typeof(CreditCardLog))
                 .ForMember("CreatedDate", f => f.MapFrom("LogDate"))
                  .ForMember("LogID", f => f.MapFrom("Id"))
                   .ForMember("EntityType", f => f.MapFrom("EntityType"))
                    .ForMember("IPAddress", f => f.MapFrom("IpAddress"))
                     .ForMember("Action", f => f.MapFrom("Action"))
                  .ForMember("Data", opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver(), "Model"));

        }

        public class CustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, string>
        {
            public string Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember,string destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
            {
                try
                {


                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = 86753090};

                    // Perform your serialization
                    var dataToSave= serializer.Serialize(sourceMember);

                    return dataToSave;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    throw e;
                }

            }
        }
}
```

but its keeps throwing circular reference exception although i have also set setting

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

in global.asax Application_Start().

is there something i have missed it will be very helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` is Json.net, but you are serialising with `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay what is the best thing i can do then ?

Comment: Try serialising using Json.net: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay i have tried that it stucks forever while serializing

Comment: @damonshahi it takes forever because of the circular reference. a circular reference means you have object A, which references object B, which has a reference back to object A. This will cause a loop that keeps creating objects A and B repeatedly in a deeply-nested object of type A until you encounter a run-time error.